# How to install DSC on Azure Windows 2016 Nano Server deployed from Microsoft's image?

Tags: azure, dsc

All information I could find regarding DSC on Nano Server suggest the DSC should be added to the server image upon creation, e.g. [Using DSC on Nano Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/nanodsc):

> DSC on Nano Server is an optional package in the `NanoServer\Packages` folder of the Windows Server 2016 media. The package can be installed when you create a VHD for a Nano Server by specifying `Microsoft-NanoServer-DSC-Package` as the value of the Packages parameter of the `New-NanoServerImage` function.

Is there any way to add the DSC to an already existing system? Namely to the one deployed from `2016-Nano-Server` image provided by Microsoft on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the DSC cab file from 2016 install media onto the nano server, then use DISM to add it.

```
Dism.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:c:\Microsoft-NanoServer-DSC-Package.cab
```

You can also try using the `Install-NanoServerPackage` [powershell command](https://github.com/OneGet/NanoServerPackage) but I've found it to be rather buggy at the moment.